Epistemic uncertainty in classical probability
I've been a statistician for a long time and have recently moved towards more information theoretic research. Because of this, the question of epistemic uncertainty in classical probability has been on my mind, particularly how to properly account for the separation of epistemic and aleatory uncertainty in simple probabilistic models.
For example, if we consider the random variable associated with a coin toss $X$, according to frequentist interpretations there is some objective $P(X=1) = p_f$ associated with the long run frequency of the outcome. This makes sense if the coin toss (or any other experiment) could truly be repeated in a completely identical way, but most physical processes are not time-invariant in such a way (or simply can't be repeated, like a particular sports match). From a Bayesian perspective $P(X=1) = p_b$ is not an objective quantity at all, but a degree of belief that may change with more or less information about the experiment.
My question is this:
For events that can not be infinitely repeated in an identical way, is there a way to account for both the event having some truly objective probability $p$ and having some transitional degree of belief under imperfect information $i$? Heavily abusing notation, something like $\lim_{i \to \inf} P(X=1 | i) = p$

Search this site for [tag:exchangeability]

Note that a Bayesian can believe in an objective reality, e.g., that $P(X=1) = p$ is a "Real Thing."  The Bayesian process updates our beliefs about $p$, not $p$ itself.

Also, maybe this helps ? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332026/can-we-think-of-a-probability-in-both-the-classical-and-subjective-sense-simulta/332218#332218

@jbowman "The posterior distribution describes the complete updated information about the unknown parameter. Remember that the Bayesian philosophy is a belief that there is not a unique true parameter value. Instead, the parameter is described by a probability distribution."
(Qiang Wu, Paul Vos, in Handbook of Statistics, 2018)
I have also heard Bayesians say that the PD approximates knowledge while the actual parameter is fixed in reality, but I'm not sure how to use this to information to separate types of uncertainty (aside from maybe a distributional measure on the prior).

In Bayesianism you can model the "true" probability $p$ as a latent random variable that represents the only aleatoric uncertainty of the system.

I believe there is a good way to do this, but what is usually suggested is what "cinch" suggested above, and I think that falls short.

In the coin example, $\mathbb{P}(X=1)=p$ is an objective attribute of the physical reality. You cannot possibly have a coin with random $p$. Frequentists treat $p$ as a constant. Bayesians treat $p$ as a random variable and assume a prior belief $b(p)$ over $p$. This enables one to have a distribution over $p$ and quantify various quantities available for random variables, such as its variance, credible intervals, etc. One cannot do this in the frequentist framework. The coin's $p$ is still fixed, of course, even for Bayesians.

@geoant, sure you can have a coin (or any physical system) with some amount of 'randomness' in $p$. Without appealing to quantum indeterminacy, you can even build a system where a parameter has no way of being known beyond a particular precision (or you could explicitly bound the amount of information about the system that can go into the calculation). Nonetheless, this question assumes that the underlying random variable has some inherent aleatory uncertainty associated with it.
